# How to properly supply a preprocessor variable for a Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am working on a project made up of multiple files of c and c++ code. I did not write the code and I am just reformatting its structure. I am using visual studio code to edit my code.

I was getting a warning that several variables were going unused when I issued the "make" command. After looking at my code, I realized that this was due to a "ifdef" statement with an identifier not defined in any of the code. I asked my supervisor about this and he said that I must supply this identifier as a CFLAG in my makefile.

I did some research but am still rather confused by the process. After looking at related stackoverflow questions, I thought I had a solution.

I went to the VSCode terminal and typed "make CFLAGS=-Dvar=DATAVIS", as DATAVIS is the name of the identifier in question. However, I still got that the variables were going unused. I am at a lost at what to try next.

Edit:

Here is my makefile code: (with solution)

```
CC=g++
RM= /bin/rm -vf

EDCFLAGS:=$(CFLAGS)
EDLDFLAGS:=$(LDFLAGS)

EDCFLAGS:= -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -std=gnu11 -O2 $(EDCFLAGS)
EDLDFLAGS:= -lm -lpthread $(EDLDFLAGS)

TARGETOBJS= src/main.o src/datavis.o src/camera.o src/housekeeping.o    

TARGET = ATIKCAM-REWRITE-1.out

all: build/$(TARGET)

build:
    mkdir build

build/$(TARGET): $(TARGETOBJS) build
    $(CC) $(TARGETOBJS) $(LINKOPTIONS) -o $@ \
    $(EDLDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(EDCFLAGS) -Iinclude/ -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    $(RM) build/$(TARGET)
    $(RM) $(TARGETOBJS)
```

Comment: If your codebase is mixed C and C++ you may need to put this define in your CXXFLAGS as well. We can't tell without seeing the Makefile.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Would putting this define in my CXXFLAGS follow the same process as what I tried?

Comment: Please, add your **code** into the **question post**. This is a requirement of the Stack Overflow, and link to other site does NOT fulfill that requirement. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile expects the `DATAVIS` macro to be defined (because of `#ifdef DATAVIS`), so your CFLAGS should just be

```
-DDATAVIS
```

what you wrote defines a macro `var` with contents `DATAVIS`.

Comment: Ok, so I should now issue "CFLAGS = -DDATAVIS", correct? Also, thank you.

Comment: Yes. that is correct.

Comment: I just tried entering "make CFLAGS =-DDATAVIS" and got the error message "make: *** empty variable name.  Stop.". Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: `make CFLAGS=-DDATAVIS` No spaces around the =

Comment: Ok, thank you, it seems to work now! I am now marking this question as solved.